# Magento 2: How to use Zend Date

Tags: magento2, date, zend-framework

In Magento 1 we are using zend_date in a following manner

```
new Zend_Date(date, 'MM-dd-Y');    or
new Zend_Date(date('M-01-Y', strtotime("+1 months", strtotime(date("Y-m-d")))));
```

But how can I use above method in Magento 2 ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

In Magento2 - Replaced `Zend_Date` with native PHP `DateTime` object/functions.

So you can use PHP **DateTime** function in Magento-2

You can get current date by below code.

For Example.

```
$currentDate = (new \DateTime());
echo $currentDate->format('Y-m-d');
```

You can get more help from : http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php

Comment: If answer help for you then please accept this answer for helpful other cummunity users.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it following way.

```
new \Zend_Date($date, 'MM-dd-Y');    or
new \Zend_Date(date('M-01-Y', strtotime("+1 months", strtotime(date("Y-m-d")))));
```

Comment: That's valid code, but even ZF1 maintainers themselves suggest to favour PHP's own `\DataTime` over `\Zend_Date` for perfomance reasons. And, if you need something in M2, it's performance.

Answer (score 2):

You can also import `Zend_Date` class at the top of your class file:

```
use Zend_Date;
```

Then, your code will work as normal:

```
$dateObj = new Zend_Date($date, 'MM-dd-Y');
```

OR, you can directly instantiate the object of the class. For this, you don't need to import the class but have to use "backslash" infront of the `Zend_Date` class name.

```
$dateObj = new \Zend_Date($date, 'MM-dd-Y');
```

**Reference:** PHP Documentation on [Using namespaces: Aliasing/Importing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)